# How to make a Thread pause in Spring mvc project?

Tags: multithreading, spring, web, deprecated

I am using a Thread in Spring mvc project to do some background working.

What I have done is

1. I write a class which extends Thread. and I added init() method to start this class.
   Whole ThreadTest.java is Below.

   ```
   package org.owls.thread.vo;

   public class ThreadTest extends Thread {

       public void init(){
           this.start();
       }

       public void pause(){
           this.interrupt();
       }

       @Override
       public void run() {
           for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++){
               try{
                   Thread.sleep(3000);
                   System.out.println("Thread is running : " + i);
               } catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
           }
       }
   };
   ```
2. edit **root-context.xml** intent to start this Thread as soon as possible when the server started.

   `<bean id="threadTest" class="org.owls.thread.vo.ThreadTest" init-method="init"/>`
3. Now is the problem. I want to make a toggle button(pause/resume) in my **home.jsp** and When I click the button it works. But I do not know how can I access to the Thread, which already registered and run.

please, show me the way~>0<

P.S
additional question about java Thread.
What method exactly means `pause` and `resume`. I thought stop is the one similar to pause, but it is deprecated. 
And `start()` is somehow feels like 'new()' not resume.
Thanks

Comment: you don't need to handle threads in Spring MVC manually. Look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899635/spring-mvc-how-to-get-progress-of-running-async-task

Comment: @JosefProcházka That is a wonderful example. but What my client wants is control background job in Java Servlet Page. So when he clicks "play/pause" button, it should pause and resume. Anyway, Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to control a thread.

if I want to pause(not stop), code should be like below.

```
thread.suspend();
```

And want to resume this from where it paused, like below.

```
thread.resume();
```

even though those methods are both deprecated.

(if somebody knows some replacement of these, reply please)

If you do not want to yellow warning in your spring project,

you can remove warning by simply add an annotation on that method.

annotation is `@SuppressWarnings("deprecated")`.

=========================================================

From here, additional solutions based on my experience.

To make automatic executing Spring mvc Thread,

I did following steps.

1. make a simple Class which extends Thread class.
2. inside that class, make a method. this will be calles by

config files. in this method. I wrote code like "`this.start();`".

1. Let Spring knows we have a Thread class that should run independently

with Web activities. To do this, we have to edit root-context.xml.

Add a bean like this.

```
<bean id="threadTest" class="org.owls.thread.vo.ThreadTest" init-method="init"/>
```

init is the method name which generated by user in step 2.

1. Now we run this project Automatically Thread runs.

Controlling Thread is not relavent with Spring, I guess.

It is basically belongs to java rules.

I hope this TIP(?) will be helpful to people who just entered world of programming :-)