# Springboot MVC - how to report status of long running HTTP request

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I am using Springboot MVC and say a HTTP call results in a long running operation :-

```
@PostMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> doSomething() throws IOException {
    this.someService.doLongRunningOperationSync(); //Long running operation. 
    return new ResponseEntity<>(org.springframework.http.HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Now, how can I periodically update the client of the progress?

This draft - https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-wright-http-progress-01.html - defines a way to report status of long running HTTP operations. Is something possible like this in springboot MVC? Any other alternative of how I can achieve this?

Comment: Please check this answer:
[Spring MVC how to get progress of running async task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899635/spring-mvc-how-to-get-progress-of-running-async-task)

Answer (score 0):

[Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Techniques for Real-time Updates](https://spring.io/blog/2012/05/08/spring-mvc-3-2-preview-techniques-for-real-time-updates/)

may be useful too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.